# How to search in sed for any name matching

Tags: sed

How to find structures matching a pattern

```
struct struct_name {
....
....
};
```

I'm using

```
sed -n -e '/struct{/,/}/p'
```

how to search for any struct_name

Comment: Are you trying to search the file for **struct_name** or get a list of the structs in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **extract *all* `struct` definitions** (POSIX-compliant command):

```
sed -n '/struct [^ {]\{1,\} {/,/}/p' file
```

More robust with respect to whitespace variations (POSIX-compliant):

```
sed -n '/struct[[:blank:]]\{1,\}[^ {]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]*{/,/}/p' file
```

Alternative, using an *extended* regular expression (works with both GNU and BSD/macOS `sed`):

```
sed -E -n '/struct[[:blank:]]+[^ {]+[[:blank:]]*\{/,/\}/p' file
```

**`awk` alternative** (`awk` *only* uses extended regexes):

```
awk '/struct[[:blank:]]+[^ {]+[[:blank:]]*\{/,/\}/' file
```

The `awk` solution has the added advantage that a given struct definition will also be extracted correctly if it is all on a *single* line: `awk` looks for the *end* of a range on the *same* input line as the start of the range, whereas `sed` does not.

---

To **extract a *specific* `struct` definition *by name***:

**`sed` doesn't support variables**, so your best bet is to **splice in a *shell variable* that the *shell expands up front***.

```sh
name='struct_name'   # define name to search for as shell var.
sed -n '/struct '"$name"' {/,/}/p' file # splice shell var. into sed script
```

<sup>Note that I've deliberately *not* used `sed -n "/struct $name {/,/}/p"` - a single, double-quoted string expanded by the shell *as a whole* - so as to make it clear which part of the `sed` script is expanded by the shell up front.</sup>

This works in this simple case, but is tricky business in general, because you must ensure that the expanded variable value contains no regex/`sed` metacharacters that break the command.

---

Here's an **`awk` alternative** that uses `awk` variables and *literal* substring matching to bypass the problem of potentially having to escape the variable value:

```sh
awk -v name='struct_name' 'index($0, "struct " name " {"),/}/' file
```

This solution has the added advantage that the struct definition will also be extracted correctly if it is all on a *single* line: `awk` looks for the *end* of a range on the *same* input line as the start of the range, whereas `sed` does not.

Answer (score 0):

This will search a text file for **struct_name**.  You can use the -E switch to use a regular expression.

```
grep -no struct_name test.txt
```

The -n switch causes the line number to be included, the -o means only the matching element of the line will be displayed.